# ImportError: cannot import name 'SKCompat'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I compiled Tensorflow from source to work with CPU. I was able to successfully install it. I used Anaconda3\python.exe to run an example, and there is an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/prac/python/tensor_test/test_3.py", line 7, in 
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn import SKCompat
ImportError: cannot import name 'SKCompat'

Comment: Try `from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python import SKCompat`

Comment: Thank you.The problem has been solved according to your suggestion.